# How to use same same s3 bucket which triggers AWS lambda to populate staging and production database

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless

Creation events in one of my S3 buckets triggers AWS lambda MyLambda which eventually saves some row in my RDS database (production).
Now I want use (same!) bucket that will trigger MyLambda-Staging (different lambda) or MyLambda:Staging (alias for MyLambda) -whatever approach I choose.

My I get stuck because of this error:

```
An error occurred when creating the trigger: Configuration is ambiguously defined. Cannot have overlapping suffixes in two rules if the prefixes are overlapping for the same event type.
```

So I wanted to create new lambda( or alias) which will use same bucket and be trigger my same suffix (because there are huge amount of files and I am interested in only one)

I don't want this solution to involve additional AWS services since I want most simple solution possible.

Comment: You need to put a SNS topic in between S3 and your Lambda. https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/triggering-multiple-lambda-from-single-s3-event-kush-vyas

Comment: You have to delete the original trigger and replace it with the sns one. Then subscribe both lambdas to the sns topic.